# Lossless Compression from ImageResizer

Tags: .net, imageresizer

Trying to get Lossless Compression from ImageResizer. What configuration do we need to use to pass the Google Pagespeed Optimize Images test? Images like this one:

http://191.237.6.205/azure/sitefinitylibraries/images/default-source/images/txdfw/_model-images/alden-iii---belmont/thumbnail-images/additionalthumbnail1_belmont_dfw.jpg?sfvrsn=4&build=5100&quality=85&encoder=wic&width=450

are failing on the Google Pagespeed test: http://bit.ly/1Ezqe1T

Receiving messages like "Losslessly compressing ... could save 15.9KiB (2% reduction)"

We are using Wic encoder, 85% quality, and resize. What configuration do we need to use?

We have our current diagnostic output available here:
https://gist.github.com/jdev1977/95be644bf93c9201b6be

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer V3 doesn't do a good job of removing that last 2-4%. You *might* get better results with the FreeImageBuilder plugin, but it's likely that some of the advanced compression techniques simply require more CPU time than we can afford to give them for an on-the-fly workflow. For WIC and the GDI+ pipeline, some of that percentage is likely some leftover metadata that we can't get rid of.

Is this percentage very significant to you?

All PageSpeed is saying is that there exists the possibility to compress the images more optimally. It can't make a judgement call on quality vs. file size - or, at least, it can't make a meaningful one. It's also running tools that are known to have very heavy resource requirements - thus the duration of the test. You wouldn't want to run those same tools to perform on-the-fly compression.

Comment: We are trying to get a achieve the best possible score for the SEO benefits and the performance benefits, we have a lot of large images on our website and we're trying to get everything possible. While what they are calling 1-2% on each of these images seems trivial, it's adding up to a 15-20 point swing on our pagespeed scores. I'll experiment some with the  FreeImagePlugin, I tried running through compressor.io with the same 2% remaining, this is very important to our current efforts. We have CDN/Varnish setup in front, so a slower performance isn't a showstopper.